# How to break the entire group when limited space in datawindow (Powerbuilder 11.5 build 2506)

Tags: break, powerbuilder, datawindow

In Powerbuilder, how can I break the entire group to another page when there is not enough space for the whole group?

I don't want to break the group every time when the content of column of the group change, but only break automatically when the page does not have enough space to show the whole group. The situation now is that it can automatically break the **detail records** into another page.

In the following example, there is a group (by Product Code), but it breaks the records into two pages when there are not enough space rather that breaking the whole group.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly confident that the behavior you described happens automatically by PowerBuilder. Anything is possible I suppose but the effort to do something manual might be steep.

Maybe you could get lucky by making some minor adjustments. Like increasing/decreasing the detail, header, footer, summary band heights. Or maybe make the groups using a sub-report (aka nested reports) and PowerBuilder might handle the display differently with a nested report. Experiment with column "shift" and "slide" settings.

Just a note... if you are changing data in the report after it has been retrieved, then make sure to sort it again via Sort() if needed and/or perform a GroupCalc() to force the dataobject to recalculate and regroup.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the group to nested report.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same problem.
The solution that fixed my problem here is that I create a nested datawindow for this detail.

If you want to print this detail on new page, 
then  create a group on the nestes dw, then on the group properties, checked the 'New page on group break'.